# Pull out certain objects from an ArrayList of Interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to call a method from a few objects in an `ArrayList` that is typed by an interface (Here we will call it interface).

```
ArrayList<Interface> obj = new ArrayList();

obj.stream().forEachOrdered((o) -> {
  if (/*If o extends ObjectA then run this next line*/) {
    o.methodCallNotInTheInterface();
        }
    });
```

My problem is `o` can only ever see the methods and variables of the interface and nothing else.

Comment: the construction should be `ArrayList<Interface> obj = new ArrayList<>();`. (Not sure if it answers the question, haven';t really looked at it yet)

Comment: I am using Java 1.8, the second <> are implied and no longer required to be there.  But thanks for trying to help ^-^

Comment: `ArrayList<Interface> obj = new ArrayList();` generates a compilation warning in Java 8. You *should* use the `<>` (diamond operator) as @amit suggests.

Comment: Since you're using interfaces (a good thing), you should `List` instead of `ArrayList` as a type

Comment: @AntonMalyshev how would you write your loop hmm? ;)

Comment: `for (Interface o: obj) { o.methodCallNotInTheInterface(); }` is rather clean to me

Comment: Can't call that (I tried) because I need (ObjectA o : obj) and that won't work because ObjectA implements Interface but does not extend.

Comment: How about `for (Object o: obj)`?

Comment: Then yes that would work after I type cast it to the right thing.  But that seems more like a hack to me then proper programming. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using a stream, you could use a predicate to filter the values you want and then apply a function to the filtered values. This function would simply cast values to the desired class.

Consider the following list of numbers:

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, new BigDecimal("2.22"), 3l));
```

Then, if you only needed to call a method on `BigDecimal` instances, you could do it this way:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(n -> n instanceof BigDecimal)
    .map(n -> (BigDecimal) n)
    .forEachOrdered(n -> System.out.println(n.pow(2))); // 4.9284
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I always love one line solutions when I can find one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the [`instanceof`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31) key word.

```
if (o instanecof ObjectA) { ...}
```

That said, [usage of `instanceof` is often indicating a code smell](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31), and your design should probably not have a method that is not implemented, and if for some reason it does have such method, make it throw an exception (`NotImplementedException`).

Comment: My question on the code smell link is such, o is an object that implements the interface that the ArrayList is typed to.  Any method call on o was only returning the methods that were declared in that interface and not the other methods that object had.  That shouldn't cause a "code smell" correct?

Comment: @JoshuaPelino You mean the interface had a method (let's say `foo()`, and `ObjectA`, which happen to extend a `SuperClass` that also has `foo()`, and you want `SuperClass`'s `foo()` to be called? If I remember correctly, in java8 you are going to need to resolve it in `ObjectA` anyway.

Comment: No the interface had a method foo() and I was trying to call the method bar() of ObjectA.

Comment: @JoshuaPelino Basically, if you have an interface, and you need to know the specific class implementing it, in order to use some functionality not supported by the interface, that's a code smell...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) operator to decide whether your object is of the correct type:

```
List<Interface> obj = new ArrayList<>();
obj.stream().forEachOrdered(o -> {
    if (o instanceof ObjectA) {
        ((ObjectA) o).methodCallNotInTheInterface();
    }
});
```

Note that `instanceof` also returns `false` if `o` is null, so you don't need to check for that.

Comment: This kinda fixed it, my problem ultimately ended up being something much more stupid. (I forgot to import that object) that's why when I tried this earlier it didn't work and I thought I had the wrong syntax. Thanks though you caused me to look at my code much more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Check first the type of `o`:

```
if (o instanecof ObjectA)
```

then cast `o` to type `ObjectA`:

```
((ObjectA)o).method();
```